# Как написать sql запрос в drupal?

Tags: drupal, sql

Добрый день. Как написать запрос, позволяющий в webform (drupal) просуммировать значения нескольких полей и занести результат в определенное поле?

Answer (score 1):

обычный select запрос  в друпале делаеться так :

```
db_select('table1','t');/*эквивалентность запроса:select t.id,t.name,t.nomer  */
->fields ('t','id','name','nomer')/* from table1 as "t"*/
->range(0,9)/* limit 9;*/
->execute();
```

Думаю это должно помоч.